# libgdx - handling objects outside cam

Tags: java, dictionary, libgdx, render

I have watched some libgdx tutorials and learnt how to use cam and use tile to make map. However I meet a little problem that I want some ideas.
I want to make RPG game but I want the game to memorize each monster's information such as location. However the map is very big so I need to reduce the amount of rendering. How can I keep information of each monster including those outside the cam without using a lot of resources?

Comment: For you large map, your will need to use a method called clipping. As for storing information, create a java object with the information you need such as position, texturereregions, and ect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming from your question that you've already worked with `TiledMap`s in libGDX. You can use an `OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer` to draw your map, which will render the correct portion of the screen for you using the `Camera` object you pass to it:

```
OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer renderer =
    new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(myMap, 1 / 16f); // Change this to your render scale
                                                  //e.g. 1/32f means your tiles are 32px wide

OrthographicCamera camera = new OrthographicCamera(16, 9); //viewport size: 16x9

...

//Inside your class that implements Screen or extends Game
public void render(float delta) {
    ...
    renderer.setView(camera);
    renderer.render();
    ...
}
```

For managing your entities, take a look at [the Ashley framework](https://github.com/libgdx/ashley/wiki/How-to-use-Ashley). You could give all of your entities a `Component` containing its position, and then create a rendering system to draw them.

You'd have to draw your entities yourself, as they are not part of the TiledMap, but for starters this implementation of a [system using `Box2dDebugRenderer`](https://github.com/RoaringCatGames/libgdx-ashley-box2d-example/blob/master/core/src/com/roaringcatgames/testgame/systems/PhysicsDebugSystem.java) might help.

If you're *not* using Box2D, here's an example of how it might look using an `EntitySystem` (not tested):

```
public class RenderingSystem extends IteratingSystem {

    public static final Family MONSTERS = Family.all(BoxComponent.class).get();
    //Assumes you've made a BoxComponent class

    private ShapeRenderer shapes;
    private Camera camera;

    public RenderingSystem(Camera camera) {
        super(MONSTERS);
        this.camera = camera;
        this.shapes = new ShapeRenderer();
    }

    @Override
    public void update(float deltaTime) {
        shapes.begin(ShapeType.Line);
        shapes.setColor(Color.RED);
        super.update(deltaTime);
        shapes.end();
    }

    @Override
    protected void processEntity(Entity entity, float deltaTime) {
        Rectangle box = entity.getComponent(BoxComponent.class);
        // ^ Could be done faster using ComponentMappers
        shapes.rect(box.x, box.y, box.width, box.height);
    }

}
```

Comment: thank you for the information, but I don't know how to use ashley framework... I am very new to programming. How can I implement the library to my project?

Comment: Do you use Gradle for building your projects? If yes you can just add these lines [here](https://github.com/libgdx/ashley/wiki/Getting-started-with-Ashley#gradle) to your gradle files and rebuild. If no, libGDX uses Gradle, so you can import it to your IDE (Eclipse/IntelliJ) by using [this](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gradle-and-Eclipse) if you use Eclipse or [this](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gradle-and-Intellij-IDEA) if you use IntelliJ. There is also a NetBeans section [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gradle-and-NetBeans).

Comment: oh, I didn't notice that Ashley was there. I haven't generated anything because I am still building my large map. I think I will include it when I generate project. Thank you very much for the information!